# Define the type of error in function argument

Tags: javascript, flowtype

How do I define the type of `error` below?

```
async function falseThrow (promise: Promise<any>, error): any {
  let value: any = await promise
  if (!value) throw error
  return value
}
```

Comment: What type do you expect it to be?

Comment: @MikeC In the above case the `error` argument is an instance of the `Error` object.

Comment: So can't you just do `error: Error`?

Comment: Isn't this the same as [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616492/flowtype-function-can-throw-error)?

Comment: @j08691 This question was about defining the`error` argument, that question is about defining the return value.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly as you defined the type of `promise` being `Promise<any>`. You use `:`.

That depends on the type you want. If error is expected to be a string, then it would be:

```
async function falseThrow (promise: Promise<any>, error:string): any {
  let value: any = await promise
  if (!value) throw error
  return value
}
```

**EDIT**

Or you could use [Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error), if that's the case, as you stated on your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works! Whoops, thought it did not.

```
async function falseThrow (promise: Promise<any>, error: Error): any {
  let value: any = await promise
  if (!value) throw error
  return value
}
```